# No command prompt within "vagrant ssh" in mintty/cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin, mintty

When I run "vagrant ssh" within my Cygwin terminal, the ssh session has no command prompt, meaning commands and results are all inline which makes it pretty difficult to work with.

[image: view]

In addition my tab-autocomplete doesn't work but I think this is normal for SSH. I've tried reinstalling terminfo and ncurses to no avail. Am I missing some other utility for this?

Vagrant is installed on the host by the way, not directly in Cygwin.

Comment: Your SSH session isn't allocating a TTY for some reason.

Comment: I worked around this by using putty instead of vagrant ssh.